# Rolling update using k8s client-go

Tags: kubernetes, client-go

I'm struggling to find an example of performing a rolling update of a kubernetes deployment using client-go. Currently I scale to 0 and then back to 1 but that causes downtime.

I wonder if there is a way to trigger a rolling update. I have nothing to change in the deployment itself. All I need is to restart a pod so that it consumes an updated ConfigMap.

I have not found a direct way to initiate a rolling update rather than editing a deployment. But this does not work for me.

Comment: Please provide code of how exactly you're trying right now.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with just updating a deployment. Introduced an env which holds resourceVersion of a configMap that I need to watch. This causes rolling update. I have not found a direct way to initiate it